# Function trait and implicit parameters

Tags: scala

The following works:

```
object X extends (Int => String => Long) {

  def apply(x:Int):String => Long = ???
}
```

How could I type an `apply` function with an `implicit` parameter?

I have the following method:

```
def apply(x:Int)(implicit y:String):Long = ???
```

How can I describe the function type?

```
object X extends <functionType> {
  def apply(x:Int)(implicit y:String):Long = ???
}
```

---

**update**

I could define it like this:

```
object X extends (Int => String => Long) { 

  def apply(x:Int):(String => Long) = ???
  def apply(x:Int)(implicit y:String):Long = ???; 
}
```

But then calling it doesn't work:

```
error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method apply in object X of type (x: Int)(implicit y: String)Long
and  method apply in object X of type (x: Int)String => Long
match argument types (Int)
              X(3)
              ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that comes to my mind is this:

```
object X {
  def apply(i: Int)(implicit y: String): Long = ???

  implicit def xToFun(x: X.type)(implicit y: String): Int => Long = x(_)
}
```

The implicit conversion will allow you to use `X` wherever `Int => Long` is needed, and the implicit `String` parameter will be resolved when that conversion is applied (not when `X.apply` is actually called):

```
val fun: Int => Long = X //error, no implicit String in scope

implicit val s = "fuu"
val fun: Int => Long = X //OK
```

Comment: You certainly gave me some food for thought, thanks!